# Custom bullets and paragraph margin-left customisation

Tags: html, css

I created some css to customize the bullets of `<li>` elements:

```css
ul { 
  list-style: none;  
} 

ul li::before { 
 font-size: 30px;
 content: "\25AA";   
 color: #cc0c10;  
 display: inline-block;  
 width: 0.8em;  
 margin-left: 0.6em;  
 transform: translateY(5px);
} 

li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

However it seems that when adjusting the `margin-left` and `width` properties it only applies to the first line and not to the whole `<li>` content, how can I achieve that?

[image]

Live Example: https://codepen.io/ehouarn-perret/pen/PMmNZN?editors=1100

Comment: The problem is that, the :before is part of the text, and it just getting inserted before the first line. Every time you are unsure about the size or the positioning of an element, add borders around it, then you will see where it starts etc... I would position the :before absolutely relative to the <li> and adding a padding-left to the <li>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated pen:

https://codepen.io/chille1987/pen/MNmydZ?editors=1100

```
ul{ 
  list-style: none;  
} 

ul li::before { 
 font-size: 30px;
 content: "\25AA";   
 color: #cc0c10;  
 display: inline-block;  
 width: 0.8em;
 position: absolute;
 top: -8px;
 left: 0; 
} 

li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vestibulum ante vel pellentesque luctus. Aenean est nulla, rhoncus ut nunc et, pellentesque varius nunc. Integer lacus massa, lacinia in turpis et, tristique ultricies ligula. Sed vel malesuada tellus, in consequat libero. Quisque dui nisi, malesuada quis libero quis, laoreet consequat ligula. Phasellus a ligula porta, tincidunt nulla vitae, elementum risus. Nulla eu dignissim ligula.</li>
  <li>Suspendisse vitae eros quis justo egestas tempus at fermentum odio. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum egestas mi tellus, at semper arcu dignissim sed. Ut tempor ligula ut eros dictum scelerisque. Ut tempus nec nisl eget dictum. Donec sagittis pharetra turpis, nec ullamcorper odio feugiat eget. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce eget sagittis nisl, ac malesuada dui. Vestibulum porta urna a fermentum sollicitudin. Nullam porta commodo urna a pulvinar. Vestibulum a semper urna. Mauris dapibus accumsan ipsum eget viverra. Suspendisse vitae tellus rutrum, egestas est in, sollicitudin urna.</li>
  <li>Pellentesque iaculis ut nunc a tempor. Donec sodales luctus tellus pretium tempor. Aenean egestas leo id ex pharetra commodo. In laoreet porttitor tellus non luctus. Nullam pretium pulvinar arcu nec sollicitudin. Quisque sed nulla imperdiet nulla commodo egestas convallis ac arcu. Sed sit amet turpis tellus. Integer luctus justo a rhoncus vulputate. Duis scelerisque accumsan nibh, vel facilisis urna eleifend sed. Suspendisse hendrerit ipsum ut velit convallis imperdiet. Sed condimentum nisl sed quam laoreet tincidunt.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)